# saveOrUpdate() in hibernate is not working, instead a select query is executed which is mentioned nowhere in the program. (using spring+hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Here is the main function, values have been set to bean.

```html
package demo.sphbIntegrate;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("sphb.xml");
        EmployeeDAO edao=(EmployeeDAO) context.getBean("d");
        Employee e=new Employee();
        e.setId(1);
        e.setName("sourav");
        e.setSalary(100000);
        edao.saveEmployee(e);
    }
}
```

This is the bean class.

```html
package demo.sphbIntegrate;

public class Employee 
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int salary;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
  
}
```

And this is my DAO class.

```html
package demo.sphbIntegrate;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;

public class EmployeeDAO 
{
    HibernateTemplate template;

    public void setTemplate(HibernateTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void saveEmployee(Employee e) 
    {
 template.saveOrUpdate(e);
    }
}
```

According to the code, the record must be entered into the table.
However, something strange is happening, a select query is performed which is mentioned nowhere in the whole program.
I am unable to wrap my head around this abnormality.
PS:I am sure, i am running the correct program and all files are saved correctly, also no code for select query is written in the whole package.

Here is the output:

```html
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Hibernate: select employee_.ID, employee_.NAME as NAME2_0_, employee_.SALARY as SALARY3_0_ from EMPLOYEE employee_ where employee_.ID=?
```

Comment: You set an `id` hence hibernate needs to check if the record exists or not.

Comment: As @M.Deinum  said since you are using id the system assumes you are trying to update the record. It looks for the record in database. Since it is not found it is not updating the data. If you want to create new data remove the id and try to auto increment the primary key field. If you want to set the id value use save method instead of using saveorupdate mehtod

Comment: Now, I understand why the select query is being fired. But the major issue is the record is not getting inserted in table either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing to worry in this scenario because `saveOrUpdate()` do both the job Saving and Updating.

It first check if the ID you are passing exist in the Table or not so for the same reason you are seeing a select query. If you observe your query carefully

```
select employee_.ID, employee_.NAME as NAME2_0_, employee_.SALARY as SALARY3_0_ from EMPLOYEE employee_ where employee_.ID=?
```

You will see `ID` in where condition.

If this query return no result then only new record would be inserted else update will happen.

Comment: Now, I understand why the select query is being fired. But the major issue is the record is not getting inserted in table either.